# R Missing Value Replacement Function

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation

I have a table with missing values and I'm trying to write a function that will replace the 
missing values with a calculation based on the nearest two non-zero values.

Example:

```
X  Tom    
1  4.3    
2  5.1    
3  NA    
4  NA    
5  7.4
```

For `X = 3`, `Tom = 5.1 + (7.4-5.1)/2`.

For `X = 4`,  `Tom = (5.1 + (7.4-5.1)/2) + (7.4-5.1)/2`

Does this function already exist?  If not, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not aware of a function that does exactly that. The `na.locf` function in pkg::zoo would "carry forward".

Comment: I don't quite understand what you meant in calculating the value of Tom for X = 4, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

A more usual way to do this (but not equivalent to the question) is to use linear interpolation:

```
library(zoo)
df <- data.frame(X = 1:5, Tom = c(4.3, 5.1, NA, NA, 7.4))

na.approx(df)
```

or spline interpolation:

```
na.spline(df)
```

Comment: Thanks!  na.approx() did the trick.  Do you know what the formula is that the algorithm uses, or how to look it up?

Comment: It uses linear interpolation.  The R `approx` command does the real work underneath.  `?approx`

Answer (score 1):

Actually the **imputeTS** package (I am the maintainer) offers a good solutions for this.

**Replacement with the Moving Average**

```
 na_ma(x, k = 2)
```

x is your input object
k is the moving average window

k of 1 means you only consider the values before and after
k of 2 means you consider the 2 values before and the 2 values after

This function is probably the closest to the required calculation.
The only difference is, that the imputeTS method does not jump over NA values. (as required by the thread starter)

But especially for long NA streaks this makes perfectly sense.
1, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 14, 15, 16
(taking the average of 2 and 14 for the NA at position 3 would be no good idea)

Furthermore **Last Observation Forward** (as mentioned by 42 in the comment)

```
imputeTS::na_locf(x)
```

or **Interpolation** (as also mentioned by G. Grothendieck)

```
imputeTS::na_interpolation(x)
```

are also missing data replacement options that go a little bit in the same direction.
Here is a [introduction to the imputeTS package](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2017/RJ-2017-009/RJ-2017-009.pdf) in the R Journal if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a loop in this scenario, other approaches are much harder.

```
for (i in seq_len(nrow(df)) {
  if (is.na(df[i, 'Tom']))
    df[i, 'Tom'] <- ((tmp <- c(0, df$Tom[!is.na(df$Tom)], 0))[i+1] + tmp[i]) / 2 + tmp[i]
}
```

## Example

```
df <- data.frame(X = seq_len(100), Tom = ifelse(runif(100, 0, 1) > 0.5, NA, round(runif(100, 0, 10), 1)))
head(df)
# X Tom
# 1 1  NA
# 2 1.4
# 3 3  NA
# 4 4 3.9
# 5 5  NA
for (i in seq_len(nrow(df))) { if (is.na(df[i, 'Tom']))  df[i, 'Tom'] <- ((tmp <- c(0, df$Tom[!is.na(df$Tom)], 0))[i+1] + tmp[i]) / 2 + tmp[i] }
head(df)
#  X  Tom
# 1 1 0.70
# 2 2 1.40
# 3 3 4.05
# 4 4 3.90
# 5 5 9.05
```