# Replace NA with previous and next rows mean in R

Tags: r, replace, na

How could I Replace a NA with mean of its previous and next rows in a fast manner?

```
  name grade
1    A    56
2    B    NA
3    C    70
4    D    96
```

such that B's grade would be 63.

Comment: What if the adjacent value is missing as well? Maybe try [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736316/r-missing-value-replacement-function/22736656#22736656) ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Or you may try `na.approx` from package `zoo`: "Missing values (NAs) are replaced by linear interpolation"

```
library(zoo)
x <- c(56, NA, 70, 96)
na.approx(x)
# [1] 56 63 70 96
```

This also works if you have more than one consecutive `NA`:

```
vals <- c(1, NA, NA, 7, NA, 10)
na.approx(vals) 
# [1]  1.0  3.0  5.0  7.0  8.5 10.0
```

`na.approx` is based on the `base` function `approx`, which may be used instead:

```
vals <- c(1, NA, NA, 7, NA, 10)
xout <- seq_along(vals)
x <- xout[!is.na(vals)]
y <- vals[!is.na(vals)]

approx(x = x, y = y, xout = xout)$y
# [1]  1.0  3.0  5.0  7.0  8.5 10.0
```

Answer (score 11):

Assume you have a data.frame `df` like this:

```
> df
  name grade
1    A    56
2    B    NA
3    C    70
4    D    96
5    E    NA
6    F    95
```

Then you can use the following:

```
> ind <- which(is.na(df$grade))
> df$grade[ind] <- sapply(ind, function(i) with(df, mean(c(grade[i-1], grade[i+1]))))
> df
  name grade
1    A    56
2    B    63
3    C    70
4    D    96
5    E  95.5
6    F    95
```

Comment: used this to do the following: If x=condition, replace x and next 2 values by mean of x-1 and x+3. which changes the code to: `ind <- which(df$grade<(-100))` and 
`df$grade[ind:ind+2] <- sapply(ind, function(i) with(df, mean(c(grade[i-1], grade[i+3]))))`
For x<-100

Comment: As an alternative to the `sapply` call, you could also use: `df$grade[ind] <- with(df, ((grade[ind-1] + grade[ind+1])/2))`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution, using the median instead of mean, is represented by the `na.roughfix` function of the `randomForest` package. 
As described in the [documentation](http://ugrad.stat.ubc.ca/R/library/randomForest/html/na.roughfix.html), it works with a data frame or numeric matrix. 
Specifically, for numeric variables, `NAs` are replaced with column medians. For factor variables, `NAs` are replaced with the most frequent levels (breaking ties at random). If object contains no `NAs`, it is returned unaltered.

Using the same examples as @Henrik,

```
library(randomForest)
x <- c(56, NA, 70, 96) 
na.roughfix(x)

#[1] 56 70 70 96
```

or with a larger matrix:

```
y <- matrix(1:50, nrow = 10)
y[sample(1:length(y), 4, replace = FALSE)] <- NA
y
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1   11   21   31   41
# [2,]    2   12   22   32   42
# [3,]    3   NA   23   33   NA
# [4,]    4   14   24   34   44
# [5,]    5   15   25   35   45
# [6,]    6   16   NA   36   46
# [7,]    7   17   27   37   47
# [8,]    8   18   28   38   48
# [9,]    9   19   29   39   49
# [10,]   10  20   NA   40   50

na.roughfix(y)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1   11 21.0   31   41
# [2,]    2   12 22.0   32   42
# [3,]    3   16 23.0   33   46
# [4,]    4   14 24.0   34   44
# [5,]    5   15 25.0   35   45
# [6,]    6   16 24.5   36   46
# [7,]    7   17 27.0   37   47
# [8,]    8   18 28.0   38   48
# [9,]    9   19 29.0   39   49
#[10,]   10   20 24.5   40   50
```