# averaging specific rows of one column based on values of another

Tags: r

I have a dataset of measurements using two techniques in succession, meaning half-hour with one technique and one hour with another (data below).

I would like to compare both techniques, so need a single point (every 1.5 hrs) from both datasets.

I want to obtain a column 5, where average of row 1 and 3 for column 4 at position row 2, meaning average of 16:00 and 17:00 value of column 4 at 16:30 timestamp so that I can compare column 2 and column 5 directly.

[image: table with sample data]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for information on how to improve your question. Sharing data as pictures is not very helpful.

Comment: Duplicate of [Replace NA with previous and next rows mean in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22916525/replace-na-with-previous-and-next-rows-mean-in-r)

Comment: This should be trivial to code, assuming your index is regular without gaps, then we don't even need to inspect timestamp values, we simply want to index row slices `0:2, 3:5, 6:8...`. Or `groupby(index // 3)`. Please post what code you've tried.

Comment: @M.: it's a trivially easy question but not a duplicate of that question: OP doesn't want to replace NAs in column 3 ("meastA"?), but create a new column "meastC" where the NAs in meastA are replaced.

Comment: a) Please post your data as text, not image. [\[MCVE\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) b) Please give your columns names, if only for the clarity of the question. If they don't have names then just pick meaningful names for them (*"average of row 1 and 3 for column 4 at position row 2"* is plain hard to make sense of). The index doesn't need a name. Suggested names: `timestamp, meastA, meastB, meastC`

Comment: (*"In each 90min window of timestamp, we have three rows: MeastA samples at +0 and +60 min, and Meast B sample at +30 min. I want to average(?)/(interpolate?) both MeastA values at the +30 min point, into a new column MeastC"*)

Comment: Thank you everyone for the comments and solution. Next time will try to post the data in correct format. Among the suggestions, replacing NA from user M works for my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have `DF` shown in the Note.  Then assuming that you want to replace NAs with a linear interpolation of the nearest non-NAs and simply extend non-NAs to fill in values at the beginning and end:

```
library(zoo)

replace(DF, 2:3, na.approx(DF[-1], rule = 2))
```

giving:

```
##   V1       V2  V3
## 1  A 1.000000 1.0
## 2  B 1.000000 1.5
## 3  C 1.333333 2.0
## 4  D 1.666667 3.0
## 5  E 2.000000 3.5
## 6  F 2.333333 4.0
## 7  G 2.666667 5.0
## 8  H 3.000000 5.0
```

If you want the average of the nearest NAs then use `na.locf` both forward and backward and then average them and finally fill in the extremities using `na.fill`.

```
library(zoo)

replace(DF, 2:3, na.fill(
                     (na.locf(DF[-1], na.rm = FALSE) + 
                      na.locf(DF[-1], fromLast = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE))/2, 
                    "extend"))

##   V1  V2  V3
## 1  A 1.0 1.0
## 2  B 1.0 1.5
## 3  C 1.5 2.0
## 4  D 1.5 3.0
## 5  E 2.0 3.5
## 6  F 2.5 4.0
## 7  G 2.5 5.0
## 8  H 3.0 5.0
```

Yet another approach is to use splines.  See `?na.spline` .

### Note

```
DF <- data.frame(V1 = head(LETTERS, 8), V2 = c(NA, 1, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 3),
  V3 = c(1, NA, 2, 3, NA, 4, 5, NA))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works for my data. however, will try it with complete dataset